# How to disable form authentication cookie in two mvc 4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two asp.net mvc 4 application with form authentication running on Windows 7 IIS, but ones is in the root domain and the other is in a specific port of the same domain.

root App: www.mydomain.com
2nd App: www.mydomain.com:8080

Both were configured in IIS 7, windows 7.

The problem i'm having is if the user authenticates and login in the 2nd application, when i go back to the root application the user is authenticated with the 2nd application username and of course the root app throws me an error that the user does not exist.

I think this problem is because forms authentication uses authentication cookie ruled by the domain.

How can i solve this problem maintaining the same domain?

Answer (score 3):

Make both applications rely on cookies of **different** names. To do this, edit the forms authentication sections of the `web.config` and set a value in one of your applications and a different value in another application:

application1:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms name="cookiename1" ... />
```

application2:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms name="cookiename2" ... />
```